# Can I display datewise JSON data (ListView) in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

I want to display JSON data on the date posted, there is a key value of date in the JSON string, Right Now I am printing the entire posted entries and it is really ugly?

I am currently using a flutter calendar weekly view which also disappears off the screen upon the day clicked. (runtime)

#### This is my Code where I am calling data

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_week/flutter_calendar_week.dart';

class WeeklyData extends StatefulWidget {
  _WeeklyDataState createState() => _WeeklyDataState();
}

var dt;
List data = [];

class _WeeklyDataState extends State<WeeklyData> {
  void fetchData() async {
    final uri = Uri.parse('My URL');
    final header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

    final response = await http.get(uri, headers: header);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            CalendarWeek(
              controller: CalendarWeekController(),
              showMonth: true,
              height: 100,
              minDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -365)),
              maxDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 365)),
              onDatePressed: (DateTime datetime) {
                dt = datetime;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("$data"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### The data gets printed fine on the screen but it's too much I want to filter only the entry according to the day clicked on the calendar

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://157.90.55.200:8040/lover/1/",
        "uuid": "bf47ddad-9362-4a12-af74-f8ad62883c60",
        "raddress": "",
        "pubkey": "",
        "active": true,
        "created": "2021-08-15T17:29:42.797000Z",
        "updated": "2021-08-15T17:29:42.798000Z",
        "day": 0,
        "dslp": 0,
        "dnpe": 0,
        "cm": "string",
        "love": 0,
        "pain": "string",
        "mood": "string",
        "diet": "string",
        "eln": "string",
        "sreq": "string"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://my url/lover/2/",
        "uuid": "25254a18-e9c2-4489-b2f6-ff5174d07ee3",
        "raddress": null,
        "pubkey": null, 
........
```

Answer (score 0):

check and used [grouplist package](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list)

```
GroupedListView<ModelClass, String>(
                //physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                elements: listData,
                groupBy: (ModelClass e) => '${e.created.subString(0,9)}',
                groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => groupByValue!="null"? Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: Text(groupByValue)):Container(),
                itemBuilder: (context, element) {
                  return Center(child: Text(element?.mode ?? ""));
                },
                order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
              )
```